# How to reduce the font size of each cell value in the existing PDF, Using Itext Library

Tags: java, itext

I want to reduce the font size to any pixel value like 2 or 3 etc.
I have the Pdf Tables like below,
[image: Input tables like below]

[image: Output table in the pdf like below]

Comment: What have you tried? How did that fail?

Comment: i tried setting setFontAndSize mehod but no use, i did not found any library which ilustrating making change for existing PDF font size.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you want, I didn't realize the "existing" when reading your question. Nonetheless, I have to disappoint you. The format pdf is not designed to allow easy changes to existing page content, in particular in a non-interactive, automatic way. E.g. you see table cells but in the pdf there most likely are a number of line drawing instructions and a number of text drawing instructions without necessarily being related other than by the coordinates of the drawings being near to each other. Scaling all text down may work but can cause the text layout not match the borders...

Answer (score 0):

Acheived like below
BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

```
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    for (String key : fields.getFields().keySet()) {

        if (!values.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println("Value not found for:" + key);
            continue;
        }

        fields.setFieldProperty(key, "textsize", 4f, null);
        fields.setFieldProperty(key, "textfont", font, null);
        fields.setField(key, values.get(key));
        fields.regenerateField(key);
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that your table cells are form fields. Had you said so, you'd have gotten an answer like this much earlier.